# Error while setting up roBERTa model in colab notebook

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I am getting error while merging vocabulary and merge txt files for tokenizers designed for Tensorflow roBERTa. I attached the error snapshot!![enter image description here][1]

Code:

```
tokenizer = tokenizers.ByteLevelBPETokenizer(vocab_file='vocab_roberta_base.json',
merges_file='merges_roberta_base.txt', lowercase=True,add_prefix_space=True)
```

ERROR:

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5dab9f2389e4> in <module>()
      1 MAX_LEN = 96
----> 2 tokenizer = tokenizers.ByteLevelBPETokenizer(vocab_file='vocab_roberta_base.json',merges_file='merges_roberta_base.txt')
      3 sentiment_id = {'positive': 1313, 'negative': 2430, 'neutral': 7974}

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tokenizers/implementations/byte_level_bpe.py in __init__(self, vocab_file, merges_file, add_prefix_space, lowercase, dropout, unicode_normalizer, continuing_subword_prefix, end_of_word_suffix)
     31                     dropout=dropout,
     32                     continuing_subword_prefix=continuing_subword_prefix or "",
---> 33                     end_of_word_suffix=end_of_word_suffix or "",
     34                 )
     35             )

Exception: expected ident at line 1 column 2
```

Comment: from transformers import *;
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base');tokenizer.save_vocabulary('.')